# How to multiply each digit of an array in the same index in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have to make this program that multiplies an like this:
The first number of the first list of the first array with the first number of the first list of the second array. For example:

```
Input
array1 = [[1,2,3], [3,2,1]]
array2 = [[4,2,5], [5,6,7]]
```

So my output must be:

```
result = [[4,4,15],[15,12,7]]
```

So far my code is the following:

```
def multiplyArrays(array1,array2):
    if verifySameSize(array1,array2):
        for i in array1:
            for j in i:
                digitA1 = j
            for x in array2:
                for a in x:
                    digitA2 = a
            mult = digitA1 * digitA2
        return mult
    return 'Arrays must be the same size'
```

It's safe to say it's not working since the result I'm getting for the example I gave is `7` , not even an array, so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want a simple solution, use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [3,2,1]])
array2 = np.array([[4,2,5], [5,6,7]])

result = array1 * array2
```

if you want a general solution for your own understanding, then it becomes a bit harder: how in-depth do you want the implementation to be? there are many checks for example the same sizes, same types, number of dimensions, etc.

the problem in your code is using for each loop instead of indexing. for i in array1 runs twice, returning a list (first [1,2,3] then [3,2,1]). then you do a for each loop in each list returning a number, meaning you only get 1 number as the output which is the result of the last operation (1 * 7 = 7). You should create an empty list and append your results in a normal for loop (not for each).

so your function becomes:

```
def multiplyArrays(array1,array2):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(array1)):
        result.append([])
        for j in range(len(array1[i])):
            result[i].append(array1[i][j]*array2[i][j])
    return result
```

this is a bad idea though because it only works with 2D arrays and there are no checks. Avoid writing your own functions unless you absolutely need to.

Comment: It's only for 2D arrays, and in this case I need to create the function myself. I believe this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: why do you need to create your own function? array multiplication is really easy with numpy. The only time I write my own functions is when I want to optimize a code where I'm sure the inputs are clean (no checks needed) by writing the function in Cython (C extensions for python run much faster than native python).

Comment: btw numpy is a bazzoka to solve so simple problem...

Comment: It's because my teacher is asking us to do it this way, and since I'm a bit behind I'm basically learning by myself, and asking my teacher outside of class time is impossible.

Comment: I updated the code to be proper list indexing (I was using numpy indexing with [i,j] but lists should be [i][j]). I still think it's a bad idea to do it this way, but if your teacher asks for it then oh well.

Comment: @EricRuiz famous last words. Most bugs in code are related to handwritten code instead of using built-in libraries and tools. Handwritten codes are never as well tested and optimized as built-in tools.

Comment: Yes, that's what we all think in class. An assignment I delivered last week was 235 lines long when it could've been only around 50.

Comment: you're welcome. Good luck with your course

Comment: @OM222O Maybe in class environments with students, the extensive use of libs for everything can make "toolish and lazy devs" in future. I mean: someone need to keep creating those great tools in future, right? If I got it right, is a lesson question to inspire the student to get some logic challenges with python, so the use of libs instead pure-language solutions in this specific case, maybe, can leads in another direction.

Comment: I feel like there are many more important things people need to learn. We had to understand indexing in a much more fun way: we were given a large bitmap (2D array of ones or zeros) that contained the ascii characters for a font. We had to read an input text and draw the output pixels. That still teaches you about proper indexing while trying to solve a real problem, rather than introducing bad practices like writing your own functions instead of using built in tools.

Comment: I agree, but you didn't got the main idea. No worries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip()` to iterate over the lists at the same time:

```py
array1 = [[1,2,3], [3,2,1]]
array2 = [[4,2,5], [5,6,7]]

def multiplyArrays(array1,array2):
    result = []
    for inner1,inner2 in zip(array1,array2):
        inner = []
        for item1,item2 in zip(inner1,inner2):
            inner.append(item1*item2)
        result.append(inner)
    return result

print(multiplyArrays(array1,array2))
```

Output as requested.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this! Could it be possible to do this without using zip?

Comment: It seems that @OM222O has something to say about that.

Comment: Yep, I'm trying it that way! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here are three pure-Python one-liners that yield your expected output, two of which are simply list comprehension versions of the other two answers. List comprehension equivalents are generally more efficient, but you should choose what is most readable for you.

**Method 1**
@quamrana's, as a list comprehension.

```
res = [[a * b for a, b in zip(c, d)] for c, d in zip(arr1, arr2)]
```

**Method 2** @OM222O's, as a list comprehension.

```
res = [[ arr1[i][j] * arr2[i][j] for j in range(len(arr1[0])) ] for i in range(len(arr1))]
```

**Method 3** Similar to Method 1 but makes use of [operator.mul(a, b)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) (returns `a * b`) from the `operator` module and the built-in [map(function, iterable, ...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function. The `map` function "[r]eturn[s] an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results." So given two lists `a` (from `array1`) and `b` (from `array2`), `map(operator.mul, a, b)` returns an iterator that yields the results of multiplying each element in `a` with the element in `b` with the same index. `list()` converts the results into a list.

```
res = [list(map(operator.mul, a, b)) for a, b in zip(arr1, arr2)]
```

**Simple Benchmark**

---

**Input**

```
from random import randint

arr1 = [[randint(1, 25) for i in range(1_000)] for j in range(1_000)]
arr2 = [[randint(1, 25) for i in range(1_000)] for j in range(1_000)]
```

Ordered from fastest to slowest

```
# Method 3
29.2 ms ± 59.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# Method 1
44.4 ms ± 197 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# Method 2
79.3 ms ± 151 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# numpy multiplication (inclusive of time required to convert list to array)
81.7 ms ± 122 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

We can see that Method 3 (the `operator.mul` approach) appears fastest and the `numpy` approach appears the slowest. There is a big caveat, of course, as the `numpy` timings included the time required to convert the lists to arrays. In order to make meaningful comparisons, we need to specify whether the input and/or output is a list and/or an array. Clearly, if the inputs are already lists and the results must also be lists, then we can be happy with standard Python approaches.

However, if `arr1` and `arr2` are already `numpy` arrays, element-wise multiplication is incredibly fast:

```
1.47 ms ± 5.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Mind exploded, excellent experiment, thank you for share! My vote is for method 3. xD

Comment: I'm curious how did you get that execution telemetry? Thx in advance.

Comment: I would suggest that you! Maybe as a timeit extension/decorator or something similar. If you search for "timeit" on pypi.org, you will see a bunch of dead packages, some are good ideas, but your solution seems great! I will be happy to follow this project :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244477/discussion-between-eric-ruiz-and-oda).

Answer (score -1):

More simpler approach without using any module.

```
array1 = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]]
array2 = [[4, 2, 5], [5, 6, 7]]

result = []

i = 0 
while i < len(array1):
    sub_array1 = array1[i]
    sub_array2 = array2[i]

    a, b, c = sub_array1
    d, e, f = sub_array2

    inner_list = [a * d, b * e, c * f]
    result.append(inner_list)

    i += 1

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[4,4,15],[15,12,7]]
```

Comment: This exactly demonstrates my point for why you shouldn't write your own functions. Using a while loop as a for loop is VERY BAD. Extracting 3 elements by hand means this code breaks if the array is anything other than Nx3. STOP DOING THIS, PLEASE! The amount of broken code I have to work with everyday is insane and it just gets worse :(

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. It's a good practice to use existing modules and functions to handle and simplify things with less amount of code. The code I posted is merely just an alternative way showing that it can also be done without using numpy module or zip() function, as OP asked in one of the comments. I know it not that dynamic if in case the length of the sub array is greater than 3.  But its gets the job done.